# Facebook's "Activity Feed" Social Plugin not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I got my code from the [autogeneration tool](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/) that they provide:

```
<script>    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    } (document));</script>
<div class="fb-activity" style="left:20px;top:5px;" data-site="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Whoreable-Clothing-Company/133131240116991/" data-width="200" data-height="200" data-header="false" data-colorscheme="dark" data-border-color="#222222" data-recommendations="true"></div>
```

But it never shows any activity even though I'm sure that a bunch of stuff has recently happened.  Does anyone know if Facebook has a workaround or a fix for this?

I found [this link](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5727015/facebook-activity-feed-not-working), which claimed to have a fix, but it did not work for me and if you read the comments you will see that others did not have much luck either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem only happening when you are logged out of Facebook and attempting to view the website?

It may have to do with your fanpage permissions settings. I wrote a blog post that will walk you through the process of ensuring that logged out Facebook users can still see your facebook social plugin's activity feed when they visit your website.

There is an image with a 3 step process that's really simple and mapped out to walk you right through this, click to zoom on the image and follow the 3 steps: http://www.profromgo.com/facebook-social-plugin-working-logged-users

If that doesn't work also try changing the dimensions of the area where you're attempting to embed the social plugin. Once in a while people have issues with it because they didn't give it enough "space" to fit properly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Blog post, image and this whole answer for (citing): „on the ‘manage permissions’ page change your age restriction settings to ‘Anyone 13+’“ :)